# Delete paragraphs in RichTextBox on button click

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I have a `RichTextBox` and some `Buttons(TEMPLET1,TEMPLET2,TEMPLET3....)`. When a button is clicked 1st time 2 paragraphs of text is added to the `FlowDocument` of the `RichTextBox`.
Below is the screenshot of the application.
 [image]

My question is, how can i delete a specific template from `RichTextBox` when i click its respective template button 2nd time.
Any ideas are welcome. It would be great if someone can give a sample code on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this site.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx

Comment: RichTextBox as name indicates, allows only text inside. Although it looks weird in your image. Try to add a listbox, whenever button is clicked "X" is added, when X is pressed you determine its number and delete appropriate line.

Comment: @Maximus can you please give a sample code as i am new to wpf. That would be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: Deleting 3 lines of text, will that also apply if you resize the window and each entry only takes up 2 lines?

Comment: @PawBaltzersen sorry for misleading, actually 2 paragraphs are added and i want to delete them on a button click. Please check my question again i have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

<del>I am not clear with your **Delete** part. Do you want to just hide it from the screen or remove the tag all together?</del>

<del>I have one simple solution if you just want to hide it from the screen.</del>

**EDIT** 
Changed the answer as you have provided me the details.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Template 1" Click="Button_Click_1" Focusable="False"/>
        <Button Content="Template 2" Click="Button_Click_2" Focusable="False"/>
        <Button Content="Template 3" Click="Button_Click_3" Focusable="False"/>
        <Button Content="Template 4" Click="Button_Click_4" Focusable="False"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <RichTextBox x:Name="rchOne">
        <FlowDocument x:Name="flowDoc" />
    </RichTextBox>
</DockPanel>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private bool paraOneAdded = false;
    private bool paraTwoAdded = false;
    private bool paraThreeAdded = false;
    private bool paraFourAdded = false;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!paraOneAdded)
        {
            Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
            para.Name = "temp1";
            para.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("Template 1.")));
            para.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            para.Inlines.Add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean Condimentum, orci eu placerat interdum, odio lacus faucibus ex, et viverra justo sem nec augue.");
            flowDoc.Blocks.Add(para);
            paraOneAdded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var myPara = flowDoc.Blocks.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "temp1");
            if (myPara != null)
            {
                flowDoc.Blocks.Remove(myPara);
                paraOneAdded = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!paraTwoAdded)
        {
            Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
            para.Name = "temp2";
            para.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("Template 2.")));
            para.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            para.Inlines.Add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean Condimentum, orci eu placerat interdum, odio lacus faucibus ex, et viverra justo sem nec augue.");
            flowDoc.Blocks.Add(para);
            paraTwoAdded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var myPara = flowDoc.Blocks.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "temp2");
            if (myPara != null)
            {
                flowDoc.Blocks.Remove(myPara);
                paraTwoAdded = false;
            }
        }

    }

    private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!paraThreeAdded)
        {
            Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
            para.Name = "temp3";
            para.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("Template 3.")));
            para.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            para.Inlines.Add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean Condimentum, orci eu placerat interdum, odio lacus faucibus ex, et viverra justo sem nec augue.");
            flowDoc.Blocks.Add(para);
            paraThreeAdded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var myPara = flowDoc.Blocks.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "temp3");
            if (myPara != null)
            {
                flowDoc.Blocks.Remove(myPara);
                paraThreeAdded = false;
            }
        }

    }

    private void Button_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!paraFourAdded)
        {
            Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
            para.Name = "temp4";
            para.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("Template 4.")));
            para.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            para.Inlines.Add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean Condimentum, orci eu placerat interdum, odio lacus faucibus ex, et viverra justo sem nec augue.");
            flowDoc.Blocks.Add(para);
            paraFourAdded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var myPara = flowDoc.Blocks.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "temp4");
            if (myPara != null)
            {
                flowDoc.Blocks.Remove(myPara);
                paraFourAdded = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

<del>I am simply toggling the `Visibility` of the `RichTextBox`.</del>

I have modified the code so that you can now delete the added templates. I hope this helps.

Comment: i want to delete(remove) 1 whole template from the `FlowDocument` of the `RichTextBox`. For example if i click `Button(TEMPLET4)` then 2 paragraphs are added to the `RichTextBox`. When i again click `Button(TEMPLET4)` then added 2 paragraphs should be deleted(completely removed). I am using only 1 `RichTextBox` and templates that are added to it are `Paragraphs`.

Comment: The code is little repetitive but I am sure you can optimize the solution.